# Accessing Kerberos NFS filer from kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, kerberos, kdc

I'm trying to access NFS filer protected with Kerberos from my kubernetes pod using keytab file. To achieve this here is what I have done so far.

1. Created Dockerfile with Kerberos tools installed in it.

Dockerfile

```
From centos:7

RUN yum -y install krb5-workstation krb5-libs nfs-utils
```

`docker build -t kerberos-centos:7 .`

2. created keytab file on my local machine for the principal account that has access to NFS filer.

```
ktutil:  add_entry -password -p PRINCIPAL@KERBEROS_REALM -k 2 -e aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
Password for PRINCIPAL@KERBEROS_REALM:
ktutil:  write_kt kerberos.keytab
ktutil:  quit
```

After generating the keytab if I do `klist` I can see the ticket details

```
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_XXXX
Default principal: PRINCIPAL@KERBEROS_REALM

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
07/27/23 15:05:28  07/28/23 01:05:28  krbtgt/XX.XXXXXX.XXXX@XX.XXXX.XXXX
        renew until 07/28/23 11:12:52
```

3. Created kubernetes secret to store the `keytab` file, which will mounted as secret file

```
kubectl create secret generic kerberos-keytab --from-file=kerberos.keytab
```

4. Created configmap to store the `krb5.conf` file, which will mounted as configmap

```
kubectl create configmap krb5conf --from-file=krb5.conf
```

5. Created PV and PVC

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-kerberos
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  mountOptions:
  - sec=krb5p
  nfs:
    path: /vol1/somepath/
    server: XXXXXXXXXXXX
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
```

PVC

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: kerberos-pvc
  namespace: XXXXX
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  storageClassName: ""
```

6. Finally created the pod template file to access the NFS share, with `kinit` command to obtain the TGT from KDC server. Pod is running with specific user using securityContext which has access to NFS filer.

Here is the pod template

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kerberos-pod
  namespace: xxxxx
spec:
  containers:
  - image: kerberos-centos:7
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: kerberos-pod
    command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - |
      kinit -V PRINCIPAL@KERBEROS_REALM -kt /etc/kerberos.keytab;
      sleep 300000
    volumeMounts:
    - name: kerberoskeytab
      mountPath: /etc/kerberos.keytab
      subPath: kerberos.keytab
    - name: krb5conf
      mountPath: /etc/krb5.conf
      subPath: krb5.conf
    - name: nfs
      mountPath: /mnt
    securityContext:
      runAsGroup: XXXXX
      runAsUser: XXXXX
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: artifactory-identity-token
  volumes:
  - name: nfs
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: kerberos-pvc
  - name: kerberoskeytab
    secret:
      secretName: kerberos-keytab
      items:
      - key: kerberos.keytab
        path: kerberos.keytab
  - name: krb5conf
    configMap:
      name: krb5conf
      items:
      - key: krb5.conf
        path: krb5.conf
```

The pods starts successfully but when I access the `/mnt` folder within the pod I get permission denied.

```
bash-4.2$ cd /mnt/
bash: cd: /mnt/: Permission denied
```

If I run `klist` within the pod I can see the TGT details.

```
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_XXXX
Default principal: PRINCIPAL@KERBEROS_REALM

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
07/27/23 15:05:28  07/28/23 01:05:28  krbtgt/XX.XXXXXX.XXXX@XX.XXXX.XXXX
        renew until 07/28/23 11:12:52
```

But if I login the kubernetes worker node with the principal account than I'm able to access the NFS share within kubernetes pod. But not sure how to access the NFS share using the keytab file.

Please assist.

Thanks in advance!